# 20.04 snapd issue: "system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image..."

Tags: 20.04, mount, squashfs

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a VPS.  I want to install certbot, but I'm having issues with squashfs - here's what I get when I `sudo systemctl status snapd` (obviously, I was lead to this error when attempting to install certbot):

```
● snapd.service - Snap Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2021-05-26 10:56:39 EDT; 16min ago
TriggeredBy: ● snapd.socket
   Main PID: 166 (code=exited, status=42)

May 26 10:56:34 vps70508.inmotionhosting.com systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
May 26 10:56:34 vps70508.inmotionhosting.com snapd[166]: AppArmor status: apparmor not enabled
May 26 10:56:34 vps70508.inmotionhosting.com snapd[166]: daemon.go:347: started snapd/2.48.3+20.04 (series 16; classic; devmode) ubuntu/20.04 (amd64) linux/5.4.0.
May 26 10:56:34 vps70508.inmotionhosting.com snapd[166]: main.go:129: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": mount: /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-635561883: mount failed: Operation not permitted.


May 26 10:56:34 vps70508.inmotionhosting.com snapd[166]: daemon.go:440: adjusting startup timeout by 30s (pessimistic estimate of 30s plus 5s per snap)
May 26 10:56:34 vps70508.inmotionhosting.com systemd[1]: Started Snap Daemon.
May 26 10:56:39 vps70508.inmotionhosting.com snapd[166]: daemon.go:589: gracefully waiting for running hooks
May 26 10:56:39 vps70508.inmotionhosting.com snapd[166]: daemon.go:591: done waiting for running hooks
May 26 10:56:39 vps70508.inmotionhosting.com snapd[166]: daemon stop requested to wait for socket activation
May 26 10:56:39 vps70508.inmotionhosting.com systemd[1]: snapd.service: Succeeded.
```

`sudo apt install fuse squashfuse` did not help in my case.

Answer (score 11):

As you're on a VPS, maybe snaps is not supported on your env.
I found this post on letencrypt, and someone said:

> snaps rely on certain Linux kernel features which are not available
> under containerized servers like those running under openvz.

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/system-does-not-fully-support-snapd-cannot-mount-squashfs-image-using-squashfs/132689

Hope this help.

Comment: Ohmigosh!  That article was the antidote - I jumped over the snapd stuff and went right to the `sudo apt install certbot` and it installed just fine.  Got my cert, and I am off and running.  Many thanks, @MrLeakim !